# Bootstrap Fileinput Form Submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-io

I am using Karjee Fileinput for my form Submission.It works well as I submit ONE photo file. But I am going to submit Two or more phote file the server can only receive the last one photo file I choose.How can I post multiple file by form input and Karjee Fileinput.

```html
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $uploadURL; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <?php
            foreach ($params as $p => $v)
                echo " <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{$p}\" value=\"{$v}\" />\n";
            ?>
        <input id="myInput" type="file" name="file" multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn-file"/>
        </form>
```

```html
    $('#myInput').fileinput({
        language: 'zh',
        allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif','JPEG'],
        maxFileCount:'4',
        showUpload: false,
        fileActionSettings:{
            showUpload: false
        }
    });
```

Comment: try adding this

<input id="myInput" type="file" name="file[]" multiple>

Comment: I finally found the way that post files without input.just use the Ajax method and use the extradata property. I think I didn’t read the document carefully.thank u answer!